# Activities to Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-viewpager

I have 3 activities which I want to convert into fragments so that I can implement a ViewPager to swipe between them:

1. Activity A ( to the left )
2. Activity B (central)
3. Activity C (to the right)

Activity B is called from an external activity and data is passed to it within the Intent. Now Activity B passes data within intents to Activities A and C when they are launched.The idea here is that B displays a slideshow with an ImageView which is updated every X seconds and A and C display information about the individual pictures.  Hence, here are my questions:

1. How do I replicate this functionality with fragments so that when I swipe from Fragment B to C and from Fragment B to A I can pass the appropriate data to them. I currently do so this way with my activities:

   ```
    Intent a = new Intent(SlideShow.this,MapsActivity.class);
    a.putExtra("long", longitude);
    a.putExtra("lang", langitude);
    pauseSlideShow(i, timeRemaining);
    isPaused = true;
    startActivity(a)
   ```
2. I read up on the differences between `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Currently, when I launch activities A and C from B I do not call `finish()` on B so that when I return to it, it is in the exact same state as before. However, since activities A and C are supporting B, when I go back to activity B from A or C I end them by calling `finish()` on A and C respectively. How can I do this with fragments?

Comment: I don't think using a ViewPager is what you need if intents are being passed between the activities because all Fragments are loaded within a ViewPager. You'd need to rewrite all the passing of data without Intents

Comment: Yes, my question is how?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using `FragmentPagerAdapter`, make sure that when you create a fragment in `getItem()` you save a reference to the fragment somewhere in the adapter or (preferably) the activity.

   Create a method (i.e. `getLatLong()`) on fragment B that returns the data.

   In fragment A in `onCreateView()`, you would get the reference to fragment B from the activity and call `getLatLong()` to get the data you need.
2. You can keep your fragments available in memory by calling `viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`. This way fragment A won't be destroyed when you swipe to fragment C, because the `ViewPager` will keep two fragments to the left of fragment C, which are your fragments A and B.

Another (probably better) approach is to create all three fragments at the beginning of the activity and return the appropriate fragment when `getItem()` is called.  By doing this, you can use `setTargetFragment()` and `getTargetFragment()` to allow the fragments to get data from one another.  When you do this, remember that a fragment may or may not have a UI available, so if you are pushing data rather than pulling, make sure the method receiving the data checks for `getView() == null`.